# ST3 SublimeLinter will not work for PHP on windows

Tags: php, sublimetext, sublimelinter

I'm having a hard time getting my sublimlinter to work for PHP. Here is my settings, if you someone experienced could take a quick look at it and let me know whats wrong with it. Thanks!

Windows System Path variable:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12;
```

SublimeLint default settings:

```
{
    "default": {
        "debug": false,
        "delay": 0.25,
        "error_color": "D02000",
        "gutter_theme": "Packages/SublimeLinter/gutter-themes/Default/Default.gutter-theme",
        "gutter_theme_excludes": [],
        "lint_mode": "background",
        "mark_style": "outline",
        "no_column_highlights_line": false,
        "paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": ["C:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.4.12"]
        },
        "python_paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": []
        },
        "rc_search_limit": 3,
        "shell_timeout": 10,
        "show_errors_on_save": false,
        "show_marks_in_minimap": true,
        "syntax_map": {
            "python django": "python",
            "html 5": "html",
            "html (django)": "html",
            "html (rails)": "html",
            "php": "html"
        },
        "warning_color": "DDB700",
        "wrap_find": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have one of the SublimeLinter-php packages installed?

Answer (score 0):

SublimeLinter is a linting *framework*, the individual language-specific linters need to be installed separately - check out Package Control for the [`SublimeLinter-php*`](https://sublime.wbond.net/search/sublimelinter-php) linters, and pick one or more that catch your eye. Please read through [the documentation](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) for complete information. There is a lot there, but I strongly advise you to read all of it, as it will save you a lot of headaches later on. Basically, you need the `SublimeLinter` package itself, which you already have, a language-specific linter like [`SublimeLinter-phplint`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter-phplint), and the linting binary (`phplint` in this case). [`SublimeLinter-php`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter-php) just uses `php -l` for linting, so a separate binary isn't needed, but depending on your needs and personal preferences you may wish to use one of the others (`phpcs`, `phpmd`).